# retrieve a mysql database via SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh

I need to copy an entire database from a mysql installation on a remote machine via SSH to my local machines mysql.

I know the SSH and both local and remote MYSQL admin user and password.

Is this enough information, and how is it done?

Comment: Do you know how to copy a database locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reading here:

Modified from http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-copy-mysql-database-remote-server.html - modified because I prefer to use `.sql` as the extension for SQL files:

> Usually you run mysqldump to create a database copy and backups as
>   follows:
>
> $ mysqldump -u user -p db-name > db-name.sql
>
> Copy db-name.out file using sftp/ssh to remote MySQL server:
>
> $ scp db-name.sql user@remote.box.com:/backup
>
> Restore database at remote server (login over ssh):
>
> $ mysql -u user -p db-name < db-name.sql

Basically you'll use `mysqldump` to generate a dump of your database, copy it to your local machine, then pipe the contents into `mysql` to regenerate the DB.

You can copy the DB files themselves, rather than using `mysqldump`, but only if you can shutdown the MySQL service on the remote machine.

Comment: I think you should edit this answer to contain the correct answer, incase the link goes dead

Comment: @MildFuzz Ok. It was the first result on a Google search for "copy mysql database from one server to another" anyway.

Answer (score 9):

From remote server to local machine

```
 ssh {ssh.user}@{remote_host} \
 'mysqldump -u {remote_dbuser} --password={remote_dbpassword}
 {remote_dbname} | bzip2 -c' \  | bunzip2 -dc | mysql -u {local_dbuser}
 --password={local_dbpassword} -D {local_dbname}
```

Comment: my only issue with this is you're having ssh run a gzip on a bzip2 stream...  it's probably better to drop the `-C` flag to ssh.

Comment: Why would you pass the password as a command-line arg? Anyone who can run ps on that machine would be able to see the password.

Answer (score 5):

That will dump remote DB in your local MySQL via [pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_pipe) :

`ssh mysql-server "mysqldump --all-databases --quote-names --opt --hex-blob --add-drop-database" | mysql`

You should take care about users in `mysql.users`

Moreover, to avoid typing users and passwords for mysqldump and mysql on local and remote hosts, you can create a file `~/.my.cnf` :

```
[mysql]
user = dba
password = foobar

[mysqldump]
user = dba
password = foobar
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [Xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup/) tool by [Percona](http://www.percona.com). It has support for hot copying data via SSH and has excelent documentation. Unlike using mysqldump, this will copy all elements of the MySQL instance including user permissions, triggers, replication, etc...

Answer (score 0):

1. ssh into the remote machine
2. make a backup of the database [using mysqldump](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/)
3. transfer the file to local machine [using scp](http://pangea.stanford.edu/computing/unix/netcommands/scpsftp.php)
4. restore the database to your local mysql